# How to replace colon (:) from all the elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, conditional-operator, mac-address

Hi let me explain what i am trying to do. I am working on a fun project just for experience.
I am planning to make a program in python in which i want to give all the mac address that are connected to my home wifi network and the program gives me an output if the mac address i gave is already in the list (that I already saved) or it is a new mac address.

I made a dictionary of all the known mac address

```
reg_mac = {
    "Device A" : "00:00:00:00:00:00",
    "Device B" : "00:00:00:00:00:00",
    "Device C" : "00:00:00:00:00:00",
    "Device D" : "00:00:00:00:00:00",
    "Device E" : "00:00:00:00:00:00"
}
```

Then I replaced all the colon from dictionary (values) and replaced it with `""` no space.

`res = {key:value.replace(':', '') for key,value in reg_mac.items()}`

And i got this

```
reg_mac = {
    "Device A" : "000000000000",
    "Device B" : "000000000000",
    "Device C" : "000000000000",
    "Device D" : "000000000000",
    "Device E" : "000000000000"
}
```

Then i asked user to input the list of mac address

```
num = int(input('Size of elements : '))
arr = list()

for i in range(num) :
  ele  = (input())
  arr.append(ele)
```

**Now i want to replace all the colon ":" from the list elements
[00:00:00:00:00] to [0000000000]

then i want to print

**if the mac address is available in our dictionary

        print "This is {key}"

    else

        print "This is a new device"**

I am new to python and in general new to computer programming. This is my first fun little project. If anybody help me in this and I completed my first ever project that will boost my interest and I will start working on new project.

by the way *I am a newbie and still taking my python course online*

Comment: If you want to look-up by the mac address, then the address should be the dict key, not its value.  That said, you can do `"000000000000" in reg_mac.values()`.

Comment: Iterate over your list via for loop then use replace().

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if there is a value in dictionary, you need to use `.values()` method.

```
if mac in reg_mac.values():
    print("This is {key}")

else:
    print("This is a new device")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. But i want to know. You can see above how i removed colon from dictionary values. I want to remove colon’s from list elements (User input Mac Address). So that i can easily compare both dictionary and list values.

Comment: So @mattarello answered you. You need to iterate over list and use `replace()` for each element.

Comment: i used this one and it worked fine for me.  

  
new_lst = [i.replace(":","") for i in arr]    
print(new_lst)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
def address_already_exists(key):
  result = []
  for i in range(6):
    result.append(key[2*i:2*(i+1)])
  return ":".join(result)

print(address_already_exists("000000000000")) # prints 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

filter on mac in list
list comprehension that splits on every 2 and joins on ":"

```
matches = filter(lambda x: x[1] in arr,reg_mac.items())

# create res dict key:value of matching macs with colons
res = {k:":".join(v[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(v),2)) for k,v in matches}
[print(k,v) for k,v in res.items()] #print k and v for each
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.items()` to find the key the value belongs to:

```
mac = input("Input mac adress: ")

for m, a in reg_mac.items():
    if mac == a:
        print(f"This is {m}")
    else:
        print("This is a new device")
```

---

You can also use only keys:

```
mac = input("Input mac adress: ")

for m in reg_mac:
    if mac == reg_mac[m]:
        print(f"This is {m}")
    else:
        print("This is a new device")
```

Answer (score 1):

So finally i found my answer and now my program is working perfectly fine.
I am sharing my working code down below:

## Registered Mac address

```
reg_mac = {
    "Device A" : "00:00:00:00:00:01",
    "Device B" : "00:00:00:00:00:02",
    "Device C" : "00:00:00:00:00:03",
    "Device D" : "00:00:00:00:00:04",
    "Device E" : "00:00:00:00:00:05",
    "Device F" : "00:00:00:00:00:06",
    "Device G" : "00:00:00:00:00:07",
    "Device H" : "00:00:00:00:00:08",
    "Device I" : "00:00:00:00:00:09",
    "Device J" : "00:00:00:00:00:10"
}
```

## Replacing : to a blank space between mac address

```
reg_mac = {key:value.replace(':', '') for key,value in reg_mac.items()}
```

## Getting input from user and replacing colon ":" from mac addresses

```
num = int(input('Size of elements : '))
arr = list()

for i in range(num) :
  ele  = (input())
  arr.append(ele)

new_lst = [i.replace(":","") for i in arr]
print(new_lst)
```

## Comparing if the given mac addresses are available in the known devices or not

```
for val in new_lst:
    if val in list(reg_mac.values()):
        print(f"the device is {list(reg_mac.keys())[list(reg_mac.values()).index(val)]}")
    else:
        print("Unknown Device")
```